# my login screen does not get any input and I cannot enter my system

Tags: fedora, kde, login, plymouth

I guess the screen is called Plymouth,  and it has started to receive no inputs since this morning and I cannot enter my password to enter the system. Restarting and shutting down did not help.  My distro is Fedora 24 and the default desktop is Plasma. As you see in the image, tge cursor is like a cross. 
[image]

And this is another picture of the boot screen before Plymouth appears.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem with Qubes (running Fedora 23 @kde). I found **it's an X related problem**.

Press `Ctrl+Alt+F3` to enter shell,

```
mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /tmp
```

Now press `Ctrl-Alt-F7` to get back to the GUI and login. Fedora will create a new `xorg.conf` on the fly. For restarting X, press `Ctrl+Alt+Backspace` on it, or if that doesn't work (GDM case), just `reboot`.

**Note that you can still login using shell interface after pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F3` if it won't work for you. From there, you can simply make a backup or do a release upgrade, following**

```
sudo dnf upgrade --refresh
sudo dnf install dnf-plugin-system-upgrade
sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=25
sudo dnf system-upgrade reboot
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks,  what is this shell screen that appears when I press ctrl, alt,f2(-f3-f4-f5). Is each of them a new environment?

Comment: My xorg.conf is located at /etc/abrt/plugins/xorg.conf. Should I still mv it to /tmp?

Comment: On running update, I get the error "failed to synchronize cache for repo fedora"

Comment: It is an usual tty console and yes, F keys will switch environments :) You can try movong to `/tmp` but, since you say you can not fetch repo it can be something else. Does `ping redhat.com` return something positive?

Comment: I realized that network is unreachable :(  ping redhat.com fails with name or service not known :|

Comment: Please, try `systemctl restart network`. If you can not manage to connect to internet, it may be more expanded failure and definitely go for clean install after backing up just `/home` dir in tty

Comment: do you mean I should install fedora again from a USB device or disk after backing up home? If so,  I'm afraid I'll lose all my application (especially those I built :(). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes. In this situation, only an upgrade could help. Actually, since you have no working internet, you can spend *time* trying to reset all configs manually, but an new install will be time-saving.